# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle Wallet Manager

Tags: sql-server, security, powershell, passwords, securestring

The [Oracle Wallet Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asowalet.htm#i1009041) allows admins to store and manage database login credentials securely by wrapping the them in a password-protected container. I have used this in the past to run VBScripts that update tables in an Oracle database, without prompting the user for a password or storing the password in cleartext in the script itself.

Now, I have written some Powershell scripts that update a SQL Server database, but I have had to store the passwords in cleartext in the scripts.

I was wondering if there was an equivalent to the Oracle Wallet feature in SQL Server? Or would I have to store passwords in a text file and encrypt it using Powershell's `ConvertFrom-SecureString`? I'm looking for a secure and flexible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way for one-off scripts, accessing specific databases, is to use scheduled tasks. You set them to run as a specific account which has the appropriate permissions, then you don't have to worry about SQL Logins or passwords.

If you want something similar to Oracle's Wallet manager, then you should look at Credentials, and Proxies in MS SQL server.

See: [Security Questions: Logins Credentials and Proxies](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2013/07/security-questions-logins-credentials-and-proxies/)

The Credential allows you to store and manage Login information.

A proxy is used by SQL Server Agent to map credentials to SQL Server Agent subsystems (i.e. PowerShell or SSIS).

Here is a link to a detailed guide on creating Credentials and Proxies and: [Run Operating System Commands in SQL Agent using PowerShell](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=sqlserver&seqNum=395)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting, this is all very useful stuff and exactly the sort of information I was looking for. Thanks for your help :D